# Returning distinct objects sorted by SearchRank involving multiple tables

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a model class called `Poll` which has `title`, `description`, and `tags` fields. I also have a `PollEntry` class (`related_name=entries`) which also has `title`, `description`, and `tags`. I am trying to implement text search (using `contrib.postgres.search`) module. There are apparently issues with returning a search ordered by rank returning duplicate objects and the Django documentation says basically "You have to be careful", but does not give any examples of how to deal with this, and I have had basically no luck finding examples online (on SO or elsewhere).

The following code snippet appears to solve this problem, but I don't know if it is the most efficient way to do this. Any suggestions or references would be much appreciated! Also, note I am using DRF here.

```
@list_route(methods=['get'])
def search(self, request):
    search_query_terms = request.query_params.get('searchQuery').split(' ')
    search_vector = SearchVector('entries__tags__name')+\
                    SearchVector('title')+\
                    SearchVector('description')+\
                    SearchVector('tags__name')+\
                    SearchVector('entries__title')+\
                    SearchVector('entries__description')
    search_query = SearchQuery(search_query_terms[0])
    for term in search_query_terms[1:]:
        search_query = SearchQuery(term) | search_query
    ids = Poll.objects\
        .annotate(rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query))\
        .order_by('-rank')\
        .filter(rank__gt=0)\
        .values_list('id')
    polls = Poll.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(polls, many=True)
    return Response(
        data=serializer.data
    )
```

Comment: Nice workaround. However, this does not include the rank on the your queryset `polls`, and therefore the rank is not in the response.

Comment: Oh you’re right. I should add that. Thanks.

Comment: Besides that, `Poll.objects.filter(id__in=ids)` doesn't keep the order so you will get the Poll objects ordered by the default order by defined in your class.